# Ensure that a control has a size in WPF: weird problem

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm having some weird issues with the WPF canvas that I cannot figure out, hope some of you gurus can :)

Here's the situation: in my application when the user clicks on an item from a list I create a new canvas, fill it with elements  and add it as a tab to a tabcontrol.

Here where the problem arises: I want to arrange the items on the canvas in a certain way, but to do that I need to know the size of the canvas. Since I just created the canvas and put it in place, it doesn't have a size yet. So what I do is call "UpdateLayout()" on it.

This gives it the correct size, but here is when things start to go wrong: as soon as I call UpdateLayout() the application CPU usage skyrockets to 100% (but the UI remains responsive, and it isn any of MY code that is causing it), and all the controls inside the canvas stop reposnding to events!!

Any idea of what may be going on?

EDIT: After further inspection I found out that it's not the "UpdateLayout()" itself causing the problems, it actually happens when I call ActualWidth or ActualHeight

Comment: Can you break in the process using a debugger and dump the stack trace? It maybe an infinite loop, for example due to a recusion in size computation.

Comment: I would use the event Canvas.Loaded and put the code with child controls initialization there (to the event handler). Because you can't receive size of control unless it is visible.

Comment: Note that if it's initialized to be collapsed, the Canvas may still receive a Loaded event yet not have determined its size.  In this case, you can wait for a LayoutUpdated event.

Comment: I investigated further, and found out that it's not actaully calling UpdateLayout that causes problems, it's calling "ActualWidth" or "ActualHeight" on the canvas AFTER having called UpdateLayout that creates the problem.
 @Simon Mourier: I must admit I'm not an expert on debugging in .NET, ho would I dump the stack trace and check it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling UpdateLayout, wrap your arrange code in a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, so that it will be evaluated a short time later.